# React-router rendered event

Tags: reactjs, angular-ui-router, react-router

Does react-router have a event fired when component is rendered? I didn't find it in it's github wiki page.
One just like this event in Angular ui-router:

`$viewContentLoaded - fired once the view is loaded, after the DOM is rendered. The '$scope' of the view emits the event.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `componentDidMount` life cycle method on the component that you are routing to.

```
var YourComponent = React.createClass({

    componentDidMount: function() {
      // Code here
    },

    componentWillUnmount: function() {
    },

    render: function() {
      return (
        <div>

        </div>
      );
    }
});

module.exports = YourComponent;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Works great!